# HTML-JS: Hide Frame from on child

Tags: javascript, html, button, frame, show-hide

So... I was looking up but my problem is the next, I have this index page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9">
<frameset rows="85,*" frameborder="No" framespacing="0">
<frame name="head" src="menu/head.jsp" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0">
<frameset cols="190,*"> 
    <frame name="menu" src="menu/menu.jsp" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" noresize marginwidth="0">
    <frame name="main" src="main.html" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0">
</html>
```

What I need is to **hide the frame: menu** from the **frame:head**, something like a button in head.jsp from which to hide and show the Menu frame

I will very much appreciate the answers you give me.

Comment: frame and frameset are not supported in html5. there are other ways of doing what you want to achieve.

Comment: You need to move your design away from frames. Make the menu a `<div>` at the top of your page, then hiding it with JS becomes easy. Failing that, use an `<iframe>` for the menu which can also be hidding from within the page. http://www.peachpit.com/blogs/blog.aspx?uk=Frames-are-Dead-Long-Live-Iframes